# Does the Network Renderer addon support multiple render layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, add-on, render-layers, network

I have a blender scene that has multiple blender layers that I would like to render using the network renderer. Are the slaves able to render out all the render layers and return the composited image to the master, or will I have to go look at the code for the addon to see if I can make this happen?

Comment: I just ran into an issue where it wasn't doing as expected. Tracked down my problem and thought I'd pass it along, since I noticed you were asking about similar issue and didn't get an answer. Hope it helps. [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65409/network-render-addon-compositing-issue/65420#65420](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65409/network-render-addon-compositing-issue/65420#65420)

Comment: @Tony Thanks for the reply. I'm sure that would have worked well, but we decided to build our own system for the time being since the network render addon seemed a bit buggy. I really appreciate the response though, means a lot.